# Move to the opposite location of a detected turtle

Tags: netlogo

I have an agent mouse and an agent cat.
When a mouse detects the presence of a cat around him, I want the mouse to rotate to the opposite positions where it detected the cat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make one agent face another with [`face`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#face). You can then make the agent turn around with `rt 180`. The result will be that they're facing exactly away from the other agent!

Comment: When I use face like this `face cat` it asks me to add a number to it, what should I put?

Comment: Found the solution, had to make it like this `face one-of cats-on neighbors` to select one of the cats near it

Answer (score 1):

When you have the option of multiple cats there might be a problem when running away from just one of them...
In that case you might want to make some weighted new direction, depending on the cats in the surroundings. But then your definition of the 'empty directions' and possible problems with multiple groups of cats coming in from different directions...

alternatively, you just move-to one-of neighbors with [count cats-here == 0]
(which will probably cause a run-time error if all neighbors harbour a cat.. :-)